# Can a workflow be submitted using kubectl instead of argo?

Tags: kubernetes, argo-workflows, argoproj

I have the file `example-workflow-cowsay.yml`:

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  generateName: hello-world-
spec:
  entrypoint: whalesay
  templates:
  - name: whalesay
    container:
      image: docker/whalesay
      command: [cowsay]
      args: ["hello world"]
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 32Mi
          cpu: 100m
```

I can submit this successfully like this: `argo submit -n workflows apps/workflows/example-workflow-cowsay.yml`.

Can I get the same thing done using `kubectl` directly? I tried the below but it fails:

```
$ k apply -n workflows -f apps/workflows/example-workflow-cowsay.yml                                                                       
error: from hello-world-: cannot use generate name with apply
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's right there in the [readme](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/blob/master/examples/README.md#argo-cli) ([version at the time of answering](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/blob/37a8a81df1d7ef3067596199f96974d31b200b88/examples/README.md#argo-cli)).

`kubectl -n workflows create -f apps/workflows/example-workflow-cowsay.yml` did the job.

---

To elaborate a bit: This makes sense, as what I was trying to "apply" was a single run of a workflow (think an object instance rather than a class). If I'd tried to apply a CronWorkflow, then `kubectl apply` would have worked. The error message that I got:

```
error: from hello-world-: cannot use generate name with apply
```

Told me about it, but I didn't understand it at the time. This is invalid:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: CronWorkflow
metadata:
  generateName: some-name
...
```

But this is valid:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: CronWorkflow
metadata:
  name: some-name
...
```

Comment: Keep question and answer clear. Move cronworkflow into another question. May mark this answer accept after moving out the cronworkflow